# How to send the contents of 1 text area to 2 forms?

Tags: html

I currently have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="http://blahblahblah.com/c2dm_send.ashx"; method="post" name="push">
<input type="hidden" name="publisherid" value="blahblah" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="YOURUSERNAME" />
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="YOURPASS" />
<input type="hidden" name="appid" value="YOUROTHERINFO" />
<input type="hidden" name="topics" value="topic_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="topics" value="" />
<p align="center">Notification Message:<br />
<textarea style="width:200px;height:100px;" name="pushmessage"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Push" />
</p>
</form>
```

Is it possible to have that same textarea apply in a second form?  I would like it if I could have an end product where the user types their message into 1 textarea and hits 1 send button but the contents of the text area are sent to two different URLs and with different "hidden" hard-coded Username and Password information for each form it is sent to.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using ASP.NET.  You could always store the information in a session variable and use it on any page you like.  Here is the documentation on session variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not in a direct way. You could make a hidden text-area in the second form, and before submiting the second form, copy the value of the visible text-area in the first form into the invisible text-area in the second form.

In that way, it looks as if the second form uses the text-area form the first form!

I did this before. If you need any help with code, you can ask :)

Comment: If I could see your code for this, that would be awesome. :)